# How to turn button into parallelogram?

Tags: html, css

I want to create buttons as seen in the following picture. But I don't have any idea, on how to reach this. So the buttons shouldn't simply be rotated, but the horizontal edges shall remain horizontal.
Can someone give me a hint or a keyword for this issue?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to create that sort of thing in the modern web is to use a clip path. Something like:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
```

Pair that with a `transform: rotate` on the text and voila.

It looks like your screenshot comes from a website. You can use the dev tools to inspect the buttons to see how they did it.

Comment: No, the screenshot is from my figma design file. But thanks for the hint with clip-path!

Comment: Won't both the div and the buttons both be transformed with ```transform: rotate;```, if its used on the parent div of the buttons? So that you dont have to use both clip-path and transform.

Comment: I'd rotate the text and have the background shape be a pseudo-element that has the clip path. You can't just do it with transforms (at least very reasonably).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `transform: skew` CSS proportion to skew the whole container.
It retains all functionality of the buttons, including `hover` effects etc. 
`Transform` is a really powerful option in CSS. Here is a little article on w3schools about it: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

If you only want to rotate it(It's a bit hard to see if it is just rotated or skewed), something like an absolute positioned `after` element applied to the container with a `transform: rotate` might be an option, which will not rotate or move the buttons.

Comment: Note: If you want to skew an element, but a child should look "normal", simply apply the skew transform to it and reverse it. 
So if you give the container a skewY(10deg), give the child a skewY(-10deg) and it'll just be straight again.